# pausing spritekit game using appdelegate in ios8

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, appdelegate

I have a pause menu in my game that I want to toggle when the i hit my home button.  it works when I'm within my game, however when I hit my home button the menu comes up, but the game will not pause.

when i restart the app, the menu is still there, but the game un-pauses itself.  It seems like spritekit automatically pauses and restarts the game on its own when you leave and enter the app.  When I'm within the app I have full control over it.  But when I'm exiting/entering the app it behaves how it likes.

Any suggestions?

```
func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication!) {
    // get the root viewcontroller
    // toggle my pausemenu method.  pause menu sets skview.paused = true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Send an `NSNotification` to `GameSceneViewController` to pause the `SKScene`:

AppDelegate:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{    
    // Pause sprite kit scene
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"PauseGameScene" object:self];
}
```

GameSceneViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(pauseGameScene)
                                                 name:@"PauseGameScene"
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)pauseGameScene {
    if (self.skView.scene) {
        self.skView.paused = self.skView.scene.paused = YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried this code?  it doesnt work.  the game will restart itself when come back into the app

Comment: If your game restarts itself when come back into the app, then the problem is definitely in your project architecture, not in the code I have posted. It works just fine.

Comment: ive tried making a basic spritekit project and using this code.  it does not work on the current xcode / ios.  are you on an old version?

Comment: heres a link to a sample project implementing this code.  you can see when you go to the home screen and come back to the app.. the game will not be paused

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4kzFbLmJr19bTlBSG5YUG1zY2s/view?usp=sharing

Comment: which version of xcode are you using?  if you click on the screen, see the rotating sprites, go to the home screen and back the sprites are paused?  how is it youre getting different result with identical code?

Comment: is there a "swift" way to do that? I'm trying to solve the same problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27655162/1139044