# game exits from pause state after resuming it from background in swift

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate

I'm developing a game with SpriteKit that can be paused during execution and can be resumed.
But I have a problem with `applicationDidEnterBackground` when the home button is pressed while the game is paused because when I resume the game the entities start moving immediately even though the game was paused before.
I cannot find a way to implement `applicationDidEnterBackground` and other related method in `AppDelegate` since there is no connection between that and my `GameScene.swift`

I'm actually pausing the entities with the code

```
entitiesLayerNode.paused = true
gameState = .GamePaused
```

EDIT:

I want to explicitly pause the `entitiesLayerNode` because I have other 'moving' nodes that I want to keep. To the problem is that with the suggestion given below that method pauses everything! I just need to pause that layer.
I think that problem is that I cannot access the `entitiesLayerNode` from the View Controller.
I generally use the snippet

```
let mainScene = scene as GameScene
mainScene.entitiesLayerNode.pause = true
```

But Xcode gives me an error that `scene` is an unresolved identifier.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much the same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26066914/pausing-spritekit-game-using-appdelegate-in-ios8/26071208?noredirect=1#comment43729002_26071208)

AppDelegate:

```
func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("PauseGameScene", object: self)
}
```

GameSceneViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("pauseGameScene"), name: "PauseGameScene", object: nil)
}

func pauseGameScene() {
    if self.skView.scene != nil {
        self.skView.paused = self.skView.scene.paused = true
    }
}
```

Comment: this works if I pause all the scene, but since I have several nodes I want to keep paused only the entitiesLayerNode, and this code seems not to work. Furthermore I cannot access skView from viewDidLoad and I have to change pauseGameScene() according to the link you sent

Comment: Well, that's your responsibility to have all necessary IBOutlets set up. I gave you a general direction, you should adapt the code to your needs by yourself.

Comment: I have no IBOutlet the interface has been coded programmatically. I have a skView in my viewDidLoad but I dunno why I cannot access it in pauseGameScene...

Comment: I temporarily solved thanks to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27262903/1139044
adding the following line in the update method of my scene             self.view?.paused = true